# Uncompress hadoop compatible snappy file

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, compression, snappy

Firehose is pushing data to s3 in snappy compressed form and [its framing format is hadoop compatible](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-kinesis-data-firehose-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/record-format-conversion.md#converting-input-record-format-console). I am downloading that snappy file and trying to uncompress in scala using [this](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java) library.

```
val input: Array[Byte] = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/prod-a8d272bb-b7af-4141-bdba-6965b343a75f.snappy"))

val uncompressed: Array[Byte] = Snappy.uncompress(input)
```

Which throws error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.throw_error(SnappyNative.java:98)
```

It is possible to generate Hadoop Snappy compatible compressed stream using SnappyHadoopCompatibleOutputStream, but in my case, I need to uncompress an already generated compressed file. Is it possible with this library ? or if not, is there any other library I could use ?

Comment: Have you tried using plain `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec` from`hadoop-common.jar`?

Comment: I want to try that, but how do i import it in my build.sbt file ? I specified these `  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.2.1",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1"` , but still cannot import `import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec`.

Comment: Managed to load `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec`, but can't figure out how to use it. Is there any good example of compression/decompression of file ?