# How to decompress snappy (hadoop file formatted) file using Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, compression, snappy

Following from my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612261/uncompress-hadoop-compatible-snappy-file) question, I've hadoop file formatted snappy compressed file and I want to decompress and write content to csv file, just like [snzip](https://github.com/kubo/snzip) tool does it,
`snzip -d /Path/to/file.snappy`. I found out that [snappy-java](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java) doesn't has support for decompressing such format. So I decided to use `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec` from hadoop common package. But I can't find any example of how to do it. Here is what I've tried;

```
object test extends App {
    val input: Array[Byte] = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/Path/to/file.snappy"))
    val s: SnappyDecompressor = new SnappyDecompressor()
    val dec = s.decompress(input, 0, input.length)
    println(dec)
```

but this gives me following output;

```
20/01/07 12:59:57 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
0
```

Bonus question: how to compress a given .csv file ?

Comment: Have you considered using **Spark** which already supports all these formats? If the file is not that big, it shouldn't be a problem to just run an embedded local spark.

Comment: files are around ~75mb in size. If it's easily doable via this library, then why go hard/long way ? I am newbe to Scala/Java, else I'd have done it.

Comment: IMHO is just much easier to use **Spark**.

Comment: That output is not an error. What's the actual problem? Please show the entire logs

Comment: Yes its not an error, but it's also not what I want. s.decompress returns an integer `0`. I don't know what to do with it :( ... and that's the complete output log.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use`setInput` (see [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/snappy/SnappyDecompressor.html)).
Something like the following should work:

```
object test extends App {
    val input: Array[Byte] = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/Path/to/file.snappy"))
    val s: SnappyDecompressor = new SnappyDecompressor()
    s.setInput(input, 0, input.length)
    var decompressed = new Array[Byte](10*1024)
    decompressor.decompress(decompressed, 0, decompressed.length)
    println(new String(decompressed, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
}
```

Comment: I think I tried this afterwards, but it throws error;
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.decompressBytesDirect()`

Comment: Before this exception, I also get `Snappy native library not loaded` followed by `Cannot load org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor without snappy library!`, is this effecting something ? Note that I have xerial.snappy library also loaded into my project.